# Vagrant provisioning scripts

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-provision

I'm pretty new to Vagrant and I've found out that the provision *.sh scripts (linked in my Vagrant file) needs to be updated. What is the best practice? Should I remove the box and re-create it? or rather "vagrant halt" and execute "vagrant provision" again?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your scipts work probably this would be enough:

```
vagrant provision
```

If your scripts require a vanilla machine to run, you need to destroy the already provisioned machine first:

```
vagrant destroy && vagrant up
```